# Running 'makemigrations' in djongo project is raising AppRegistryNotReady

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am using Djongo in django for using mongodb. I tried to migrate the models all the models get migrated but when i need arrayfield. and when i am trying to migrate it. Its rasing error. I tried all things what i was able to find on internet.I tried Django.setup in manage.py field i tried all things please help me.

code for my setting

```
Django settings for questions project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.12.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'w6(hj1%1d=kc%z^$@0z4&r(02&00jz#-t%ql2l7g&#3+!(csjr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'multi_questions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'questions.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'questions.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'question',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

code for my manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
import django

def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'questions.settings')
    django.setup()
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

code for my models.py file

```
from djongo import models
class multi_choice(models.Model):
    choice_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    options = models.ArrayField(model_container=multi_choice,size=4,default=list)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

The error what its showing while making migration is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 9, in main
    django.setup()
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/web_projects/questions/multi_questions/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/web_projects/questions/multi_questions/models.py", line 10, in Question
    options = models.ArrayField(model_container=multi_choice,size=4,default=list)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 225, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_container, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 87, in __init__
    self._validate_container()
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 91, in _validate_container
    for field in self.model_container._meta.get_fields():
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 734, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(include_parents=include_parents, include_hidden=include_hidden)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 794, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 707, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 678, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 178, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/goodwin/Desktop/env/web_dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 140, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

please help me this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Trying downgrading djongo version to 1.3.1 as the latest version doesn't support Models yet.

```
pip install djongo==1.3.1
```